# How to debug an Ionic App that uses SQLite

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, sqlite, ionic2

I would like to ask about a general direction to debug an Ionic App with Sqlite. Background: I was following [this page](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/12/use-sqlite-in-ionic-2-instead-of-local-storage/) to try to create an app to store some of my inputs.

Running `ionic serve`, maybe expectedly, we hit the error `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: sqlitePlugin`.  Some said that we shouldn't run `ionic serve` for testing Native functions like SQLite.

So I run `ionic emulate ios`, and in the Debug Log we have the same error.

As in the blog, I `CREATE` table in `app.ts`.  And when I go to the Terminal (I am using a Mac) and type `sqlite3 test.db` then I put the `CREATE` query in, everything runs fine.

Thus, the problem seems not with the "SQL", but with the connection.  However I have no idea how I can log more about the connection to DB, nor how I may show error logs in the emulator (or the Debug log is what I can have?). Seems I don't have convenient functions like `mysql_error()` to show what happened during the `CREATE`...

I have also tried to run `ionic upload` so I can test the app on my iPhone with [Ionic View](http://view.ionic.io/).  However I don't know if there is a debug console - all I can test is to tell that "it doesn't work".

Instead of a specific question, this is meant to ask for general tools / strategies that can be used to debug the SQLite functionality of an Ionic App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run your application on device(ios/android) and debug it. As plugins are not supported to desktop you won't able to debug it on desktop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I `ionic upload` it so I can test it with Ionic View on my iPhone.  All I can do is seeing nothing except the HTML... I have no idea if the Table is created nor a record is inserted when I click the Add button.  What should I do to debug it on phone?

Comment: I am not much aware of "ionic upload" command, but if you use "ionic run android"  this will run app on android device. then if your device OS is greater than 4.4 then you can inspect it using "chrome://inspect/#devices"